# Im getting an error on Google Login on Identity server

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin, identityserver3

i have implemented the google login on my Identity Server 3, however, after the login process, im getting this error:
[Error after logging][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RctcW.png

My client id and secret is correctly configured and the external providers are correctly configured too apaarently. What should i do?